Use an integrated fingerprint reader on HP 6710b with linux, Fedora 41
The HP 6710b laptop have an integrated fingerprint reader, how can I use it with Linux on Fedora?

Start by obtaining the PID&VID of the device by running lspci or lsusb then just google it + linux (xxxx:xxxx linux) and investigate whether or not it is already supported.

the easiest way to find out, though, is to simply install figerprintd and trying to enroll your fingers.

I used dmesg, lspci with grep finger and no result the lsusb has AuthenTec, Inc. AES2501 Fingerprint Sensor. The fprintd.x86_64 fprintd-pam.x86_64 is instaled on my fedora, but I don't have any idea how to integrate these or tested. Need more info.

There's nothing else to test yet: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:08ff-2580

I tested with Fedora 41 not work on my laptop , maybe is broken. I cannot enroll my fingerprint:
dnf5 reinstall fprintd.x86_64 fprintd-pam.x86_64 --assumeno

the finger print commands are :
fprintd-enroll  fprintd-verify fprintd-delete  fprintd-list


Why would it be broken? As already commented: Not (yet) supported, that's all.
